# Nest Use typeorm：I don't understand why this.navigationRepository.find() returns an empty array？

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, nest

Data exists in the database.

I have used `@InjectRepository(Navigation)` for instantiation.

I don't understand why `this.navigationRepository.find()` returns an empty array.

But when I use `this.navigationRepository.query()` I can get the data I want.

why?

Service：

```
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Navigation } from '@libs/db/entities/navigation.entity';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import {
  UpdateNavigationDto,
  CreateNavigationDto,
  QueryNavigationDto,
} from './dto';
@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Navigation)
    private readonly navigationRepository: Repository<Navigation>
  ) {}

  async create(createParams: CreateNavigationDto) {
    Logger.log(`请求参数1：${JSON.stringify(createParams)}`);
    const res = await this.navigationRepository.findOne({
      where: { title: createParams.title },
    });
    console.log('res', res);
    // return null;
    const list = await this.navigationRepository.insert(createParams);
    console.log('list', list);
    return list;
  }

  async findAll(
    queryParams: QueryNavigationDto
  ): Promise<ResultData<Navigation[]>> {
    Logger.log(`请求参数2：${JSON.stringify(queryParams)}`);
    const where: any = {};
    queryParams.page = queryParams.page || 1;
    queryParams.limit = queryParams.limit || 10;
    if (queryParams.title) where.title = queryParams.title;
    if (queryParams.id) where.id = queryParams.id;
    const list = await this.navigationRepository.find({
      where,
      order: {
        id: 'DESC',
      },
      skip: (queryParams.page - 1) * Number(queryParams.limit), // 分页，跳过几项
      take: queryParams.limit, // 分页，取几项
      cache: true,
    });
    console.log(list);
    const total = await this.navigationRepository.count();
    const totalPage = Math.ceil(total / queryParams.limit);
    const result: ResultData<Navigation[]> = {
      page: queryParams.page,
      limit: queryParams.limit,
      total,
      totalPage,
      list,
    };
    return result;
  }

  async findOne(id: number): Promise<Navigation> {
    const getOne = `select * from Navigation where id = ${id}`;
    const list = await this.navigationRepository.query(getOne);
    console.log('query', list);
    return list;
  }

  async update(id: number, updateNavigationDto: UpdateNavigationDto) {
    const list = await this.navigationRepository.update(
      { id },
      updateNavigationDto
    );
    return list;
  }

  async remove(id: number) {
    const list = await this.navigationRepository.delete({ id });
    console.log('delete', list);
    return list;
  }
}
```

Module：

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NavigationService } from './navigation.service';
import { NavigationController } from './navigation.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Navigation } from '@libs/db/entities/navigation.entity';

@Module({
  controllers: [NavigationController],
  providers: [NavigationService],
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Navigation])],
})
export class NavigationModule {}
```

Controller：

```
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Post,
  Body,
  Put,
  Param,
  Delete,
  UseFilters,
  Query,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { NavigationService } from './navigation.service';
import { ApiBody, ApiOperation, ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { HttpExceptionFilter } from '../../exception/httpException.filter';
import {
  UpdateNavigationDto,
  CreateNavigationDto,
  QueryNavigationDto,
} from './dto';

@Controller('navigation')
@ApiTags('navigation')
@UseFilters(HttpExceptionFilter)
export class NavigationController {
  constructor(private readonly navigationService: NavigationService) {}

  @Post()
  @ApiOperation({ summary: '创建导航' })
  @ApiBody({ type: CreateNavigationDto, description: '参数' })
  create(@Body() createNavigationDto: CreateNavigationDto) {
    return this.navigationService.create(createNavigationDto);
  }

  @Get()
  @ApiOperation({ summary: '获取导航列表' })
  findAll(@Query() queryNavigationDto: QueryNavigationDto) {
    return this.navigationService.findAll(queryNavigationDto);
  }

  @Get(':id')
  @ApiOperation({ summary: '获取单个导航' })
  findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.navigationService.findOne(+id);
  }

  @Put(':id')
  @ApiOperation({ summary: '更新导航' })
  update(
    @Param('id') id: string,
    @Body() updateNavigationDto: UpdateNavigationDto
  ) {
    return this.navigationService.update(+id, updateNavigationDto);
  }

  @Delete(':id')
  @ApiOperation({ summary: '删除导航' })
  remove(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.navigationService.remove(+id);
  }
}
```

Entity

```
import { Column, Entity } from 'typeorm';
import { BaseEntity } from './baseEntity';
import { Color } from './color.entity';

@Entity('navigation')
export class Navigation extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 5,
    nullable: false,
    default: '',
    unique: true,
    comment: '导航标题',
  })
  title: string;
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: true,
    default: '',
    comment: '导航图标',
  })
  icon: string;
  @Column({
    type: 'tinyint',
    nullable: true,
    default: 1,
    comment: '类型: 1: 展示标题, 2: 展示图标, 3: 全部展示, ...',
  })
  type: number;
  @Column({
    type: 'tinyint',
    default: 1,
    nullable: false,
    comment: '是否显示导航, 1: 显示, 2: 隐藏, ...',
  })
  hidden: number;
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: true,
    default: '',
    comment: '导航颜色',
  })
  color: string;
}
```

I tried to use `this.navigationRepository.find()` to get the data in the database, but I didn't get it. I don't understand why this is? I would like to get help.

Comment: Can you please provide your code as a code sample within the post, not as an image? So we can read your code easily.

Comment: Is the github link ok?

Comment: No. Copy the code into the question itself.

Comment: It's OK.  Question has been modified.